# The video I recorded via webcam with opencv does not open

Tags: python, opencv, tkinter

i tried to make a webcam video recording to a file using openCV python, i could not open the file with any of my video players. here is the code,

it works fine but I stop the recording and looking the file and it doesn't open. I guess there are some codec issues. I tried also (*'XVID') .avi format. but changed nothing.

here is the code

please help

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image 
import cv2 
import threading

root = Tk()
root.geometry("750x500")
root.configure(bg="#0059aa")


#camera
camera_frame = LabelFrame(root, text=u"KAMERA STREAMING",
                     border=2,
                     width=398,
                     height=265)
camera_frame.place(x=183,y=33)

camera_label = Label(camera_frame,width=55,height=14)
camera_label.grid(row=0,column=0)

global capture
capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0) 

# edit: close following two lines
# capture.set(3,250)
# capture.set(4,225)

global out 
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('blabla.mp4', fourcc, 20.0, (640, 480))

global stopCam
stopCam = False


def show_frames():

    global capture
    # read the capture
    ret, frame = capture.read()

    # turned into image and display
    cv2image = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    height, width, channels = cv2image.shape
    img = Image.fromarray(cv2image)
    imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image = img) 
    camera_label.imgtk = imgtk
    camera_label.configure(image=imgtk,width=width,height=height)

    # record
    global out
    out.write(frame)

    # quit
    if (stopCam):       
        out.release()
        capture.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        return

    camera_label.after(20,show_frames)



p1 = threading.Thread(target=show_frames)


buttonLabel = Label(camera_frame) 
buttonLabel.grid(row=1,column=0)

connectButton = Button (buttonLabel, text=u"connect", command=p1.start, width=14)
connectButton.grid(row=0,column=0)

stopButton = Button(buttonLabel, text=u"stop", command= lambda: globals().update(stopCam=True) , width=14)
stopButton.grid(row=0,column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

edit (also solved way):

I looked at some code that worked properly. and I saw capture.set() as the difference. When I close the capture.set() lines, I had no problems with either streaming or recording. Now the main problem is that I have to show the video in a label with a certain size. Without set() the video size gets too big. how can i solve it now?

Comment: It's crucial that you .release the VideoWriter in the end. Otherwise you won't get w working video file. Did you verify that your stop-code is called? You could try .avi video with mjpg if you are in doubt about the codec support. Aldo check the video file size. If it is only a few kb your app probably can't access the ffmpegblib during runtime.

Comment: can you please look at the question again, i solved it different way, also I will do yours too. thank you @Micka